# Google map search box

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to search places using search box in google map api .I am using Google Map Javascript api v3 .When I try to search some place it is not happning .Can anyone help me what could be the issue.Here is the html and javascript code snippet.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"
    />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input
        id="pac-input"
        class="controls"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search Box"
      />
      <div class="container" id="map-canvas"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
        center: {
          lat: 12.9715987,
          lng: 77.59456269999998,
        },
        zoom: 12,
      });

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
          lat: 12.9715987,
          lng: 77.59456269999998,
        },
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
      });

      var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
        document.getElementById("pac-input")
      );

      google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, "place_changed", function () {
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var i, place;
        for (i = 0; (palce = places[i]); i++) {
          bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
          marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
        }
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        map.setZoom(12);
      });
    </script>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Test.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your page as posted is not valid (unclosed `<style>` tage).  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the issue

Comment: Also read: [How to use google autocomplete address search box with maps](https://devnote.in/how-to-use-google-autocomplete-address-search-box-with-maps/)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```js
 function init() {
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
     center: {
       lat: 12.9715987,
       lng: 77.59456269999998
     },
     zoom: 12
   });


   var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('pac-input'));
   map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(document.getElementById('pac-input'));
   google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
     searchBox.set('map', null);


     var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

     var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
     var i, place;
     for (i = 0; place = places[i]; i++) {
       (function(place) {
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

           position: place.geometry.location
         });
         marker.bindTo('map', searchBox, 'map');
         google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'map_changed', function() {
           if (!this.getMap()) {
             this.unbindAll();
           }
         });
         bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);


       }(place));

     }
     map.fitBounds(bounds);
     searchBox.set('map', map);
     map.setZoom(Math.min(map.getZoom(),12));

   });
 }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<div class="container" id="map-canvas" style="height:300px;"></div>
```

Comment: How can i customize it my custom loaction not found in particular location, i want to show error my "clinics are not found in this particular locations"

Answer (score 8):

1. there is no `place_changed`-event for a `SearchBox` (it's an event of Autocomplete). The event for a `Searchbox` is called `places_changed`
2. there is a typo `palce`

   ```
   for( i = 0; palce = places[i]; i++)
   ```
3. It's not clear what you are trying to achieve, you iterate over the places(there may be multiple places) and set the position of a single Marker to the location of the current place. The result will be that the Marker is always placed at the location of the last place of the returned results(makes no sense to me).
   When you want to have multiple Markers you must create separate Markers for each place(and additionally remove previously added markers ), when you want a single Marker use the [Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#add_autocomplete) instead.

```js
 function init() {
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
     center: {
       lat: 12.9715987,
       lng: 77.59456269999998
     },
     zoom: 12
   });


   var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('pac-input'));
   map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(document.getElementById('pac-input'));
   google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
     searchBox.set('map', null);


     var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

     var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
     var i, place;
     for (i = 0; place = places[i]; i++) {
       (function(place) {
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

           position: place.geometry.location
         });
         marker.bindTo('map', searchBox, 'map');
         google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'map_changed', function() {
           if (!this.getMap()) {
             this.unbindAll();
           }
         });
         bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);


       }(place));

     }
     map.fitBounds(bounds);
     searchBox.set('map', map);
     map.setZoom(Math.min(map.getZoom(),12));

   });
 }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<div class="container" id="map-canvas" style="height:300px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you it worked for me.Thank you for your information can yo help me how to create separate markers for each place .

Comment: I've added an example

Comment: How can i customize it my custom loaction not found in particular location, i want to show error my "clinics are not found in this particular locations"